# How to add Android Studio Project to existing Project

Tags: java, android

So I created a project in Android Studio which is working fine, now I want to add another project from github. I tried every single instruction on the internet but I can only add the project but don't use it. So how am I supposed to use the activities from the new project. I tried opening the new project separately which also works fine, but I want to start the activities from the new project within my own project. Importing was fine and Gradle didn't show me any errors so how can I use the activities from imported projects?
Thanks for helpful answers.

Comment: Android Studio is a project based IDE. If you want "sub modules", that requires messing with Gradle. That doesn't prevent you from installing both applications on the app and starting the others activities, though

Comment: Like I said, i read a lot of instructions and successfully integrated the new project in Gradle but I still couldnt use the activities from the other project. Unfortunately I am not at home, I will show You the code from my Gradle Files and give you some more informations.

Comment: It's not really something that is meant to be done - merging activities applications.

Comment: What do you mean by "its not really something that is meant to be done" I thought that its pretty normal to merge two projects or to add a new project to your existing project.

Comment: I would need to see the Github project... Like Android libraries are meant to be integrated. Applications, not so much.

Comment: Thats my Project with the Project_2(Github Project): https://s17.postimg.org/9xc4cb527/Project.jpg

The Github Project:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-PdfRendererBasic

I added in the build.gradle in the dependencies: compile project(':app:libraries:Project_2')
And in settings.gradle: include ':app:libraries:Project_2'

So is there a possibility to use this project from github in my project?
I Would like to open the activity from the second project within my first project.

If you need more information just let me know.
Thanks so far

Comment: Yeah, you can't just clone a new application into a folder of the other one. As far as I can tell, you essentially need to copy `PdfRendererBasicFragment.java` into your own code (along with any other resources that needs)

Comment: Could You please check again what I wrote because I Accidentally clicked on "Add Comment" before i finished writing.

Comment: Yeah, I saw it. I don't think you need to open the only activity in that project. It just loads the Fragment which opens a sample PDF file.

Comment: I tested it with my pdf file i just had to change the folder path to my pdf file and it worked fine And i just want that to work in my project so i can "send" pdf files to that activity to view my pdf files within my App. If that wont work do You have any other suggestions how i could make that work?

Comment: Just give a different file path? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268161/sending-data-between-activities

Comment: I think you didnt get the point. I know how to send Data between activities. My problem is that I want to be able to send or even see the activities from the project i added in my own projects activity.

Comment: You just said you tested some PDF and it worked, so I assumed you figured that out...  Like I said, that Github project isn't written to be *imported* into your application. It is meant to be an *example* of how to open PDF, and no more than that. The code there is meant to be copied manually into your own app, as necessary.

Comment: I already tried that out but there were a lot of files to copy and adjust but i will give it a try again.
Thanks a lot for your Time.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. There should be one Fragment class, and it's layout XML that you need to copy. You don't need the Activity, Gradle files, `test/` folder, or anything else out of the `res/` folder

Comment: Hey, I just copied the Fragment and the Main Activity into my project and added the xml files. I still had to make some little changes but it works now!
Thanks